# How to implement an action when a Text is entered into EditText

Tags: android

Like read a txt file from sdcard, take every word one by one then do something with the extracted words.
like

```
String  mm = blure.getAbsolutePath();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mm));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 

        text.append(line);

        text.append('\n');
```

then something get every word and do something with it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (s.toString().contains("my")) {
                        //do something
                    }
                    else
                        //do something
                }


               @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

implement `EditText.OnEditorActionListener
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int action, KeyEvent keyEvent)`